# How to align content in two columns with bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some `html` content that I want to align and distribute as `two columns` beneath each other, of equal content.

But on mobile divices, I'd like the content to be stacked as one column.

How could I achieve this using `bootstrap` css?
I tried as follows, which did not work:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                     //the content to distribute
                </div>
            </div>
```

Additionally, I cannot use `css columns` as I have to support IE8+9.

Comment: Just use CSS columns.

Comment: I cannot use `columns` as Ie8+9 is not supporting them.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. If you want to split the contents into columns, you'll either have to use CSS columns or wrap it within child elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     //first half
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     //second half
  </div>
</div>
```

The col-xs-12 tell the column to be at full screen when using mobile phones (or small screens).

The col-sm-6 tell the column to be at half size of  the row when using any higher size devices.

I suggest reading [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

## ----Edit----

If you want to use columns css- also for ie8,9 you can check this js plug in:
http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: But this would mean I'd have to add the content twice? Once for the first half, and once for the 2nd half? I only have one content div, and this should be distributed as two columns, without having to explicit set which content goes to which column

Comment: @membersound updated answer to include a columns css (or js) based solution

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this i think please take a look

```css
.tt{
    border : 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 tt">
            first half
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 tt">
            second half
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the working demo code..

**[Demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/ov28uumu/)**

Comment: @membersound please take a look on answer

Comment: Using this, I could neither add the content just once and let the css distribute the content equally to two column, nor does it scale responsively.

Comment: so are you dynamically adding the content or what.?

Comment: Yes I'm adding the content dynamically.